# How to make the Master Bone not fall behind

Tags: rigging

So I have a basic IK rig with the controller bones, and hip bone parented to a master bone that moves the entire rig. But how can I make it so that when I use the hip bone and the IK controller bones to move the character forward, the master bone follows along so that it stays in place for when I want to rotate/move the entire character? 
[image: Here is what I mean]

Comment: You need to decide whether you're going to make a static walk cycle (like he's walking on a treadmill, he actually doesn't move forward in Pose mode) or a real walk (he's really moving from point A to point B in Pose mode). In the first case, as it is a treadmill walk, you will have to create an animation for the whole armature so that it moves from point A to B, or use a follow path. In the second case he will naturally move forwards. So in both case you won't need to move the root bone. It may be interesting to move the root bone in some cases, but please explain your situation.

Comment: @moonboots my goal is to be able to switch between the two methods easily. Maybe it’s not even possible

Comment: yes it is possible, for example the character walk through a room with a walk cycle following a path, then he has an action where he doesn't follow a path anymore but moves forwards within the Pose mode

Comment: @moonboots so would I just parent the armature object to the path instead of using a masterbone?

Comment: your armature should always have a root bone but you may not have to move it in Pose mode. For a long walk use a walk cycle then a Follow Path constraint. For a small action like the character moving 2 meters no need for a Follow Path, create a move within the Pose mode but you don't need to move the root, it might be useful sometimes though.

Comment: @moonboots But wouldn’t the root bone be left behind in the shorter walks?

Comment: yes that's it, it doesn't need to follow